# An infinite family of Artin-Schreier polynomials which all split in $\mathbf{F}_q(\!(\theta)\!)$

Tags: extension-field, valuation-theory, formal-power-series, local-field

Let $\mathbf{F}_q$ be a finite field with $q$ elements and let $K$ denote the local function field $\mathbf{F}_q(\!(\theta)\!)$. Let $R$ be its valuation ring $\mathbf{F}_q[\![\theta]\!]$. Let $u$ be a unit in $R$ which is not in $\mathbf{F}_q^{\times}+\theta^q R$.

Let $x\in K$ be such that the Artin-Schreier polynomial $X^q-X+u^{\ell}x$ splits in $K$ for all $\ell\geq 0$. Does this imply $x\in R$?

> Some remarks:
>
> 1. If $u$ would have been in $\mathbf{F}_q$, then $x=k^q-k$ for some $k\in K\setminus R$ would have provide an element $x\notin R$ such that $X^q-X+u^{\ell}x$ splits in $K$ for all $\ell\geq 0$.
> 2. Note that if $x\in \mathfrak{m}=\theta \mathbf{F}_q[\![\theta]\!]$, then the polynomial $X^q-X+u^{\ell}x$ splits in $K$, admitting the converging series $u^{\ell}x+u^{q^{\ell}}x^q+u^{q^2\ell}x^{q^2}+...$ for root in $K$.
> 3. As Jyrki Lahtonen pointed out, if $u$ would have been $1+\theta^{q+1}$ and $x=k-k^q$ for some $k\in K\setminus R$, the considered polynomials would also have split in $K$.
> 4. The combination of 1.-3. explains the condition $u\notin \mathbf{F}_q^{\times}+\theta^q R$.

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: It's too late in the evening for me to A) think straight and B) check everything, but... may be something like $x=\theta^{-q}-\theta^{-1}$ and $u=1+\theta^{q+1}$ will work? Then we have
$$u^\ell x=\theta^{-q}-\theta^{-1}+r_\ell,$$
where $r_\ell\in\mathfrak{m}$. It's clear how to get the terms $\notin R$, and $X^q-X$ is additive so...?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you! That is indeed working. Do you know whether all counterexample $u$ are congruent to 1 modulo $\theta^{q+1}$?

Comment: The above smacks a bit of cheating. Basically substituting $X\to X+\theta^{-1}$ to the polynomial you have in case $x\in\mathfrak{m}$. I think you may be looking for something else?

Comment: That's one of the things I was worried you might ask :-) I don't know the answer. Need some shut eye. I will bookmark this. May be tomorrow will be wiser :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen EDITED! Waiting for your counter-example...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes $x$ must be in $t\Bbb{F}_q[[t]]$.

Assume it is not.

Let $\rho(g) = g^q-g$ then $\rho(g+g_2)=\rho(g)+\rho(g_2)$.

Check that  $\rho(\Bbb{F}_q[[t]]) = t \Bbb{F}_q[[t]]$.

You said that $u = b+t^m h$ with $b\in \Bbb{F}_q^\times,h\in \Bbb{F}_q[[t]]^\times $ and $m\in 1 \ldots q-1$.

As you assume that $xu^l\in \rho(\Bbb{F}_q((t))$ for all $l$, for $n$ large enough you'll have $x(u^{q^n}-b) \in t \Bbb{F}_q[[t]] \subset \rho(\Bbb{F}_q((t)))$ so $xb\in \rho(\Bbb{F}_q((t)))$, and hence $q | v(x)$.

Both $xb,xu\in \rho(\Bbb{F}_q((t))$ will give that $x t^m h \in \rho(\Bbb{F}_q((t)))$ so $q | v(x t^m h)= v(x)+m$.

As $q\nmid m$ this is a contradiction.

Comment: That's it @reuns, thank you!